# slow query mysql didn't find the right index

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

I've got a "slow query" and didn't find the "right" index to avoid the slow query.

The query is  :

```
SELECT c.uid FROM tx_gwcalendar_competition c,tx_gestionprofildb_discipline d WHERE c.hidden=0 and c.deleted=0 and c.discipline=d.uid and d.usergroup=19 LIMIT 1;
```

and my tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tx_gwcalendar_competition` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tstamp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `crdate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cruser_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sys_language_uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `l10n_parent` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `l10n_diffsource` mediumtext,
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `hidden` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `title` tinytext,
  `discipline` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dept` tinytext,
  `ville` tinytext,
  `distance` tinytext,
  `date` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  KEY `parent` (`pid`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`,`hidden`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8659 ;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tx_gestionprofildb_discipline` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tstamp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `crdate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cruser_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `hidden` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `libelle` tinytext,
  `description` text,
  `usergroup` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sportup_tag` tinytext,
  `form_mutation` text,
  `documents` text,
  `mutation` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nolicence` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `agendahtml` text,
  `objectifhtml` text,
  `havestat` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `description_conseil` text,
  `frais_admin` tinytext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  KEY `parent` (`pid`),
  KEY `deleted_hidden_libelle` (`deleted`,`hidden`,`libelle`(20))
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=53 ;
```

When I Run a explain I got  that :

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  c   ALL deleted NULL    NULL    NULL    8658    Using where
1   SIMPLE  d   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   tbs888dbnew.c.discipline    1   Using where
```

I try to put an index on delete / hidden, but now change I still with 8658 key_len for the first row, like If I didn't put any index... my knowledge in mysql are limited, so I didn't know what to do (and if it's possible...).

So if someone have any advice, feel free.

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the order of `deleted` and `hidden` in your `deleted_hidden_libelle` index definition, or change the order they appear in the where clause of your query.

They should appear in the index in the same order they appear in the where clause.

In addition, you should add an index for the field you are using to JOIN the tables :

```
KEY `discipline` (`discipline`)
```

Comment: I just try it but nothing change... stil the same result.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, I try to add the discipline key, but nothing change... I'm lost. Thanks